# LRU cache design

Tags: java, cache

**Idea**

The cache is nothing but a circular `arrayList`. This list contains `Entry<K,V>`. Whenever new entries are coming, add at the end of the list. That means least recently used element at the first. Suppose if you are reusing any element then unlink from the list and add at the end.

In order to get any element, we need to traverse the list, which takes \$O(n)\$ time complexity. In order to avoid this, I'm maintaining `HashMap<K,IndexNode<Entry>>`. Here, `k` is key and `IndexNode` will contain a pointer to the `Entry` in the list so we can get the \$O(1)\$ time complexity.

**Working solution**

```
package lrucache;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class LRUCache<K, V> {

    private transient Entry<K, V> header = new Entry<K, V>(null, null, null, null);
    public HashMap<K,IndexNode<Entry<K,V>>> indexMap = new HashMap<K,IndexNode<Entry<K,V>>>();
    private final int CACHE_LIMIT = 3;
    private int size;

    public LRUCache() {
        header.next = header.previous = header;
        this.size = 0;
    }

    public void put(K key,V value){
        Entry<K,V> newEntry = new Entry<K,V>(key,value,null,null);
        addBefore(newEntry, header);
    }

    private void addBefore(Entry<K,V> newEntry,Entry<K,V> entry){
        if((size+1)<(CACHE_LIMIT+1)){
            newEntry.next=entry;
            newEntry.previous=entry.previous;
            IndexNode<Entry<K,V>> indexNode = new IndexNode<Entry<K,V>>(newEntry);
            indexMap.put(newEntry.key, indexNode);
            newEntry.previous.next=newEntry;
            newEntry.next.previous=newEntry;
            size++;
        }else{
            Entry<K,V>  entryRemoved = remove(header.next);
            indexMap.remove(entryRemoved.key);
            addBefore(newEntry, entry);
        }
    }

    public void get(K key){
        if(indexMap.containsKey(key)){
            Entry<K,V> newEntry = remove(indexMap.get(key).pointer);
            addBefore(newEntry,header);
        }else{
            System.out.println("No such element was cached. Go and get it from Disk");
        }
    }

    private Entry<K,V> remove(Entry<K,V> entry){
        entry.previous.next=entry.next;
        entry.next.previous = entry.previous;
        size--;
        return entry;
    }

    public void display(){
        for(Entry<K,V> curr=header.next;curr!=header;curr=curr.next){
            System.out.println("key : "+curr.key+" value : " + curr.value);
        }
    }

    private static class IndexNode<Entry>{
        private Entry pointer;
        public IndexNode(Entry pointer){
            this.pointer = pointer;
        }
    }

    private static class Entry<K, V> {
        K key;
        V value;
        Entry<K, V> previous;
        Entry<K, V> next;

        Entry(K key, V value, Entry<K, V> next, Entry<K, V> previous) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
            this.previous = previous;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LRUCache<String, Integer> cache = new LRUCache<String, Integer>();
        cache.put("abc", 1);
        //cache.display();
        cache.put("def", 2);
        cache.put("ghi", 3);
        cache.put("xyz", 4);
        cache.put("xab", 5);
        cache.put("xbc", 6);
        cache.get("xyz");
        cache.display();
        System.out.println(cache.indexMap);
    }
}
```

**Output**

> ```
> key : xab value : 5
> key : xbc value : 6
> key : xyz value : 4
> {xab=lrucache.LRUCache$IndexNode@c3d9ac, xbc=lrucache.LRUCache$IndexNode@7d8bb,
> xyz=lrucache.LRUCache$IndexNode@125ee71}
> ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can instead use a [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), which lets you get the in access order if you made it with the (int, float, boolean) constructor.

Then adding means removing `map.entrySet().iterator().next().remove()` if it becomes too large.

However LinkedHashMap is specially designed to let a subclass decide when to remove the oldest entry using the removeEldestEntry which gets called on each put:

```
public class MyLRUCache<K,V> extends LinkedHashMap<K,V> {

    private static final int MAX_CACHE = 4;

    public MyLRUCache(){
        super(MAX_CACHE, 1, true); 
        // sets the super class to use access order instead of insertion order.
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(
            java.util.Map.Entry<K, V> eldest) {
        return size() > MAX_CACHE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered composition instead of inheritance?

Comment: @janos except linkedHashMap was designed for inheritance. the first part assumes you were still using composition

Comment: Oh I see. Composition would be the *natural* thing to do here, except the `LinkedHashMap` is just not flexible enough to allow this. So we have no choice, it forces us to extend, which sucks, but the most reasonable solution here

Comment: @janos: Actually, no. You could let an inner class inherit from `LinkedHashMap` and expose methods on an outer one.